# UWP on screen back button - how to trigger system back event?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a UWP app - the design has a "Back" button in the screen content, which I would like to use to trigger the system navigation event handled in my `App.xaml.cs` file. My current click handler, which is pasted to each file which needs it is:

```
Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
if (rootFrame.CanGoBack)
    rootFrame.GoBack();
```

How would I instead trigger the back event, which would trigger the back event handler which already contains this code?

Comment: Have you taken a look at template 10. It wires up all this boiler plate code for you.

Answer (score 0):

In App.xaml.cs, add this to OnLaunced(...):

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    if (rootFrame == null)
    {
        ...
        // Register a handler for BackRequested events
        SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += this.OnBackRequested;
    }
    ...
}
```

Where in OnBackRequested(...), which can also be in App.xaml.cs:

```
private void OnBackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

    if (rootFrame.CanGoBack)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        rootFrame.GoBack();
    }
}
```

This could easily be adapted to support multiple frames if you implement any custom navigation, and you can also add global handling of showing/hiding the back button via something like:

```
public void UpdateBackButton(Frane frame)
{
    bool canGoBack = (frame?.CanGoBack ?? false);

    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = canGoBack
        ? AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible
        : AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
}
```

You can programmatically call back via a function like this in App.xaml.cs or in a custom navigation manager:

```
public bool TryGoBack(Frame frame)
{
    bool handled = false;

    if (frame?.CanGoBack ?? false)
    {
        handled = true;
        frame.GoBack();
    }

    this.UpdateBackButton(frame);

    return handled;
}
```

Comment: I already have all of this - what I'd like to do is fire that same `SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested` from a `HyperlinkButton` in the app's content area.

Comment: Check updated solution for `TryGoBack` function that can be called in event handler for HyperlinkButton.

Comment: Your edit is a repeat of my question, but more explicitly stated. I have a `TryGoBack`-like method in each Page code behind file which requires it.

Comment: Why raise an event when you can explicitly go back via a method call? Instead of duplicating the logic, though, you can simplify the flow by adding a custom navigation manager or derive a custom Page from the base Page that can manage some of the common navigation logic.